# Is it possible to put NULL records as last results on a ORDER BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, sql-order-by

This is my SQL query :

```
SELECT     TOP (200) IDA
FROM         Categories
WHERE     (IDA = 72)
ORDER BY Order
```

but it puts the records with Order `NULL` before the records with Order as `int`. Is there a strategy to change this order? Putting the records with `NULL` at the bottom of the result list.

Comment: Don't know about SQL Server, but in Oracle you can do ORDER BY Order NULLS LAST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for any type:

```
select top(200) IDA from Categories
order by case when [order] is null then 1 else 0 end, [order]
```

Comment: I need to write it also on select, if it is distinct! Not so well to see, but ok...

Comment: Do you mean you want the distinct values from the top 200 by order? You can just add an outer query like "select distinct IDA from (#) sub" pasting my answer as the inner query. Your original example had 'top 200 IDA where IDA = 72' which would only have one distinct value.

Comment: seems that also putting `SELECT DISTINCT case when [order] is null then 1 else 0 end, [order]` works, what do you think about?

Comment: That is allowed because you're distinct-selecting fields that are in the order by clause i.e. to stop error "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.". However its a totally different query, just to be clear.

Comment: So it executes the order by with the case 2 time? one at order by, one at select distinct?

Comment: No it only executes the order by one time. The query in your comment selects data based on field [order] not field [IDA] and so is different. But if it works thats fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
SELECT     TOP (200) IDA
FROM         Categories
WHERE     IDA = 72
ORDER BY 
   CASE 
       WHEN [ORDER] IS NULL 
       THEN 0 
       ELSE 1
   END DESC, [Order]
```

Comment: Right, but that's not what you originally had. And why not say `THEN 2 ELSE 1 END`, then you don't need `DESC`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes I messed it first time. And I think it the same as `THEN 2 ELSE 1 END` will make them come first as well. Sorry